# How to add a local repository in kickseed-based install?

Tags: 12.04, installation

According to the [Ubuntu installation
guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/), automated
installs are possible using kickseed, a subset of the RedHat's
[Kickstart](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) configuration.  The [automatic
install](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html)
section of the installation guide details the differences between RH's
kickstart and Ubuntu's kickseed.

However, nothing is written about the [repo](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html) command, which in
Kickstart is used to enable additional repositories.  The format of RH
and Ubuntu repositories is different: just the repository URL is
enough to identify the repo in RH derivatives, whereas a line in
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` carries more information.

Can anybody please post an example of a `repo` line in Ubuntu's
kickseed, or point me to the appropriate documentation? (Or even the
relevant section of the kickseed source code?)

(Background story: I want to automate Ubuntu installs; our standard
install includes some packages that are not publicly available, and
that we distribute via a local private repository.)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround seems to use the `preseed` command (documented in the Ubuntu install guide as a Kickseed-specific addition) to embed a snippet of
the corresponding D-I configuration, defining additional repositories
as would be done in a preseed-format file.

For example:

```
    preseed apt-setup/local0/comment string My repository
    preseed apt-setup/local0/repository string http://www.example.org/packages/${distro} ${suite} main
    preseed apt-setup/local0/source boolean true
    preseed apt-setup/local0/key string http://www.example.org/packages/public.gpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source in [the kickseed repo](https://github.com/aaronknister/kickseed/blob/master/handlers/repo.sh) the repo directive has been extended to support a few more options:

```
--distribution
--components
--source
--key
```

So to add the Google Chrome repo, this should do:

```
repo --name="Google Chrome"  --baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ --distribution stable --components main --key http://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```